# iOS 5 Sequence change in UITableView - viewForHeaderInSection and heightForHeaderInSection switched

Tags: uitableview, ios5

Oh woe is me - iOS 5 has broken my app.

I have a UITableView and prior to iOS 5, the delegates where called in the sequence

1. viewForHeaderInsection (which allowed me to dynamically create my
   header view)
2. heightForHeaderInSection (which allowed me to
   provide the adjusted height of the headerView

I've just checked now and run the program in the iOS 4.3 simulator and the iOS 5.0 simulator (and iOS 5 device) and the exact same code is invoked in the reverse sequence in iOS5 . WHY !!!!

The docs state (for tableView:heightForHeadInSection:)

"**Special Considerations**

Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual height for each section header in this method."

Nowhere does it state that they've quietly changed the sequence of calls.

My Question: Has anyone come across this, and any suggestions on resolving this? Do I recode everything ? I need to have a variable height header whose height I can only determine when I've created the headerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I observe the same behavior. 
You create the header view in `tableView:heightForHeadInSection` and reuse it in `viewForHeaderInsection` instead of creating it twice.

Prior to 5.0, you have to do a similar thing for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if the height is known only after constructing the view.

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like this to fix it:

// iOS 5 and later still expect a height when returning nil

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

```
// Do some check on if this section has a header
if ([navigationSections_[section] hasHeader]) {
    return 0;
} else {
    // This will use the default height
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight;
}
```

}